# SDK2 query for counting: which is more efficient?

Tags: rally

I have an app that is displaying metrics about defects in a project.

I have the option of making one query that returns all the defects, and from that I can break out about four different metrics (How many defects escaped QA in 90 days, 180 days, and then the same metrics again but only counting sev1/sev2 defects).

I could make four queries and limit the results to one so that I just get a count for each.  Or I could  make one query that encompass them all (all defects that escaped QA in 180 days) and then count up the difference.

I'm figuring worst case, the number of defects that escaped QA in the last six months will generally be less than 100, certainly less 500 worst case.

Which would you do-- four queryies with one result each, or one single query that on average might return 50, perhaps worst case 500?

And I guess the key question is-- where are the inflections points?  Perhaps I have more metrics tomorrow (who knows, 8?) and a different average defect counts.  Is there a rule of thumb I could use to help choose which approach?

Comment: I am not sure, but I would think that using four queries would be more efficient in terms of data pull, as they are all async calls. However, you would also have to manage the multiple callbacks, instead of waiting for one. I might be analyzing this wrong, but this is my initial eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would probably make the series of four queries and use the result count. If you are expecting 500 defects that will end up being three queries each with 200 defects anyways.

The solution where you do each individual query and use the total result count would be safe with even a very large amount of defects. Plus I usually find it to be a bad plan to think that I know the data sets that an App will be dealing with. Most of my Apps end up living much longer and being used on larger datasets than I intended.

Answer (score 0):

The max page size is 200, so it sounds like you'd be requesting between 1 and 3 pages to get all the data vs. 4 queries with a page size of 1 and using the TotalResultCount...

You'd definitely have less aggregation code to write if you use the multi query approach (letting the server do the counting for you based on your supplied filters).

I'd guess the 4 independent queries might be faster but it would be interesting to hear back your experimental results...